# On compact set defined by functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Let $\phi_1,...,\phi_k$ be linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $c_1,...c_k\in\mathbb{R}$  and 
$$H = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n |\;|\phi_j(x)|\leq c_j,\;j=1,..,n\}$$
Under what conditions is $H$ compact?
So my intuition tells me we must have $k\geq n$, and $\phi_1,...,\phi_k$ and at least $n$ of them must be linearly independent in the dual space, not sure how to prove it though, since we're working with a system of inequalities rather then equalities. That is, my idea was to write:
$$|\phi_1(x)|\leq c_1\implies |\alpha_{11}x_1+...+\alpha_{1n}x_n| \leq c_1$$
$$|\phi_2(x)|\leq c_2\implies |\alpha_{21}x_1+...+\alpha_{2n}x_n| \leq c_2$$
...
$$|\phi_k(x)|\leq c_k\implies |\alpha_{k1}x_1+...+\alpha_{kn}x_n| \leq c_k$$
Though not sure where to go from there...

Comment: Do you mean that the $c_j \in \Bbb R$?  Because I don't know what $\vert \phi_j(x) \vert \le c_j$ means if $c_j \in \Bbb R^n$!  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, my bad, it was a typo

Comment: I'm pretty sure your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The set $H$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$ by construction, so by the Heine Borel theorem, it is compact if and only if it is bounded. This is the case if and only if the functionals $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_k$ span the dual space. If they don't span the dual, then they have a non-zero common kernel and that common kernel is contained in $H$ which thus is unbounded. On the other hand, if they span the dual, then one easily concludes that the image of $H$ under each linear functional is bounded, which easily implies that $H$ is bounded.

Comment: How does the image of $H$ being bounded implies $H$ to be bounded?

Comment: Take the elements of the dual of the standard basis, so $\phi_i(x)=x_i$ for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. So you get information like that $x\in H$ implies $|x_i|\leq a_i$ for some constant $a_i$ and all $i=1,\dots, n$ and this implies that $H$ is bounded.